# Filling Pseudoephedrine script in Egypt

Tags: health, drugs, egypt

I’ve been given a doctors script (in Egypt by an Egyptian doctor) for Clarinase (a pill that includes Pseudoephedrine / Loratadine), but the pharmacist has said this is not available in Egypt at all.

Can anybody confirm if this is true, or recommend a course of action to get the script filled?

I’m in Sharm El-Sheikh, Nama Bay. (Ideally without going back to the international hospital I got the script from, as it’s hard to get in to see the doctor). Thanks

Comment: Go to a second pharmacy. It is possible they have a substitute, or the pharmacy will look further to check other names of the medicament. Else try to convince them to call the doctor/hospital which did the script. Try an old pharmacy (usually they known how to deal such cases: they should not trust either computers nor doctors (both fails, but we have pharmacists for such extra checks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Giacomo ‘s comment, I went to an alternative pharmacy that was a larger older shop and they could fill it but asked me to come back in a few hours for them to procure it from wherever. Must have been lost in translation somewhere along the way. Thanks!

Comment: I'm in doubt if this answer should be a comment or not.